# Качество видео в теге <video>

Tags: javascript, html

При встраивании видео через тег `<video>` качество меньше чем у оригинала который лежит на сервере.

Почему так происходит? Может качество подстраивается под скорость интернета? Можно ли как то контролировать качество- например задать на определенном уровне? Как это осуществить?

Comment: Для начала, что значит "качество меньше"?

Comment: @andreymal https://goo.gl/yBYWPA вместо того что справа, то что слева(визуально). Когда на Ютубе ставишь Качество 144- вот такой же эффект наблюдается, только в <video>, вроде как, нету настроек качества.

Comment: У видеофайла всегда строго одно качество, оно никем нигде не подставивается и нигде никак не контролируется. Качество всегда будет строго такое, какое оно записано в видеофайле. Если вы говорите, что качество портится, то мне ничего не остаётся, кроме как попросить предоставить саму страницу и сам видеофайл, потому что так не бывает, я вам не верю и, возможно, вы что-то не договариваете (возможно, не осознавая этого)

Comment: Проверил скрипт и понял, что действительно подключаю видео в меньшем качестве. Согласно политике сайта лучше удалить вопрос или оставить в качестве предостережения другим- более тщательно проверять все перед тем, как задавать вопрос,  в качестве подсказки о том, что тег <video> не производит обработки видео, а просто встраивает его в страницу?

Comment: Согласно политике вопрос должн быть закрыт как «из-за опечатки», а удалять или не удалять — это, наверно, на вкус автора (если народ не заплюсует, закрытый вопрос удалится автоматически). В качестве подсказки можно было бы оформить отдельный вопрос-ответ типа «Управляется ли как-нибудь качество в теге video? И может ли качество измениться само по себе?» (но мне заниматься этим лень)